# Movie where aliens plan to move Earth out of orbit so their planet can take its place

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a movie title but I don't have a lot to go on.   This is what I have:

An alien has crashed on Earth, and as the only survivor of his team, continues with plans to use a bomb to send Earth out of orbit and allow the orbit of his home planet to take its place, because the aliens want their planet to orbit nearer to the Sun.

Comment: Hi, welcome to scifi.stackexchange!  Can you think of any more details, say when you saw it or what language it was in?  Was it in the theatre or on TV?

Comment: Interesting. It's great idea to shift your planet in habitable zone of other star and kick the original planet out. After all, migration to another planet can be very tedious.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 1):

Could this be [Satan's Satellites](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0052160/)?

> Feature version of the 1952 serial "Zombies of the Stratosphere. "
>   Alien invaders plan to use a Hydrogen bomb to blast Earth out its
>   orbit so Mars can replace it.